# Fixing a syntax error of a mid function in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working in VBA excel and I'm trying to write a mid function but I keep getting a syntax error and I can't figure it out.

Here's the code:

```
Mid=("RXOTRX", "8", "7");
```

Comment: This line would be invalid even if `Mid` wasn't a [reserved word when used as an lvalue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266166(v=vs.60).aspx). What did you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to use the VBA `Mid` function, then your code should look something like this:

```
MidValue = Mid("RXOTRX", 8, 7)
```

Note that in your example, the start position would be past the end of your search string `"RXOTRX"` so it would return a zero-length string (`""`).

Additional documentation about the `Mid` function can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Wrong link. VB.NET is a different thing.

Comment: Thanks guys for replying, I figured it out, I used the wrong string and a couple of syntax things, I fixed it though, thanks!

Comment: For reference the VBA link is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251677.aspx) - only difference I can see from the VB.NET one is around Unicode and `MidB`